# Make private computer's IP accessible by server using Java

Tags: java, apache, proxy, ip, tunnel

To say in other words: My computer has an IP address 1.1.1.1 and the server has an IP address 2.2.2.2. My computer can access the server's IP 2.2.2.2 and work with services running on its ports (Apache, SOCKS proxy etc.). But the server can't do the same with my computer - my ISP doesn't allow it - it means when I run an Apache service on my computer on port 80, the server isn't able to call 1.1.1.1:80 (the call won't pass ISP's firewalls and reach my computer).

So, is there a way (but not contacting the ISP) to allow the server to call my IP address with successful response?
I will need some Java code to do that.

I mean creating some sort of "tunnel" which my computer opens to the server and makes the computer's IP accessible through the tunnel.

Comment: Yes, take a look at SSH tunneling.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, superuser.com would probably be a better place for it.

Comment: Well its not a question of programming until I need to open the tunel using Java. I should edit the question.